# How do I set a different kotlin version for flutter app? (I guess)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using a flutter package "flutter_ironsource_x" to get ironsource ads showing in my app.

When attempting to build, I get an error as this:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: C:/Users/myname/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/683fded33b117c0eb9bb9deabca1a71e/work-runtime-2.7.0-api.jar!/META-INF/work-runtime_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_ironsource_x:compileDebugKotlin'.
Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I added these lines (buildscript) in my build.gradle afterwards, while changing the org.jetbrains.kotlin version in two places:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.15"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.1.15"
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.1.14'
}
```

Tho, on the buildscript part I have an yellow highlight on the kotlin line, which on hover says,

```
Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.1.15) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.6.10)
```

Could some help me out? Its been some while trying to get it to work.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to android/build.gradle
and set the kotlin version to the latest one
like this

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```